# why printf using ctypes from python does not print number as signed

Tags: python, integer, ctypes, signed

I wrote the following code in C

```
short a = 0xFFFE;
printf("hex = 0x%X, signed short = %d\n", a & 0xFFFF, a);

Output ---> hex = 0xFFFE, signed short = -2
```

Now tying to do the same in Python using ctypes

```
from ctypes import *
mc = cdll.msvcrt
a = c_short(0xFFFE)
mc.printf("hex = 0x%X, signed short = %d\n", a, a)

Output ---->    hex = 0xFFFE, signed short = 65534
```

I am not sure why the output is different? Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf` isn't being called correctly.  Use `%hX` and `%hd` for passing shorts.

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> mc = cdll.msvcrt
>>> a=c_short(0xFFFE)
>>> mc.printf('hex=0x%hX, signed short=%hd\n',a,a)
hex=0xFFFE, signed short=-2
28
```